# Namespace Windows.Phone.Speech not available

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to reproduce the basic TTS example
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj207057(v=vs.105).aspx

When I type:

```
using Windows.Phone.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer;
```

The "Speech" namespace is not available. I am getting the following error:

> The type or namespace name 'Speech' does not exist in the namespace
>   'Windows.Phone' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

This is my reference folder:
[image]

Any ideas of what could be wrong?

Comment: You must add reference from .NET with name: System.Speech.dll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your project is a Windows Phone 8.1 RT and not Silverlight.
The namespace Windows.Phone is available in Silverlight based apps only.

You can have a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.media.speechsynthesis.aspx) link.

In case, you want to create a Silverlight based app, you will have to create a new project having "(Windows Phone Silverlight)" at the end of the name and then try to create your app.